# Converting a Web Site Project to a Web Application Project vb .net app_code

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am following the guidelines from

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project.aspx

Mid way through the process they have you rename your App_Code  to Old_App_Code folder and compile ... at which point i had DLL's in my BIN folder and i started to repair my aspx/ascx files.
e
Today i find the compiled bin files missing an now all my pages are sqwaking they cannot find the numerous Public Class - Public Shared Function's ...  I have verified their build action to Compile but am unable to rebuild an have them regenerate on account of project errors.

Advice on how to rebuild the bin or how to properly reference a Public Shared Function? My VB code includes an Imports statement taht used to find the class in app_code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the App_Code folder makes all the code available to the rest of the app. You have a couple options..

1). Rename the folder "Old_App_Code" back to "App_Code"

--OR--

2). Create a separate "Class Library" project, put all the classes in it, and add a reference to that project from the web project

option #2 is probably the best solution because you can begin to separate your code from the presentation "layer" offering the potential for easy re-usability, However, if it's just a one off site, whatever works for you will work..

Comment: Thank you - your approach seems to work fine. - Create a separate "Class Library" project, put all the classes in it, and add a reference to that project from the web project